# Wald test failing to reject null hypothesis that a predictor is insignificant in regression when t-test on terms involving predictor show significance

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, statsmodels, wald-test

I am running a logistic regression using a set of several predictors as well as several interaction terms. For each predictor, I am running a Wald test in statsmodels to test whether or not a predictor is significant in my model. I am doing this by testing the joint hypothesis that all terms involving the predictor (individually and in interaction terms) are zero. In some instances, I am unable to reject this null hypothesis, yet at the same time I can find instances of the predictor's interaction terms individually appearing significant in the result returned from statsmodels' summary method. So a contrived example would be, I check whether or not all coefficients for terms involving x1 are zero using a Wald test and find that I cannot reject the hypothesis that they are zero, but then looking at the interaction terms individually, I find the interaction term x1x2 has a p-value <0.05. How can this be possible? Is it perhaps an indication that the wald_test function I am using is not testing the hypothesis I think it is testing (i.e. I have specified it incorrectly in the r_matrix)?

Comment: computational aside: The `wald_test_terms` method is also computing joint tests that all parameters involving a subterm are zero. You can use it to compare it with your results

Comment: The wald_test_terms seems to be giving what looks like identical results to the summary method output for pvalue.

Comment: The joint acceptance region of an omnibus test and that of a set of tests of mutually exclusive components of the omnibus test *must* differ, unless the component tests 'pay attention to' the values of coefficients that are not part of the hypothesis in some specific ways. For example, in an ordinary regression the joint acceptance region for a set of coefficients is a (hyper-) ellipsoid but that for each of the coefficients individually is the product of univariate intervals (i.e. a hyper-rectangle or "box"). With large $n$ a GLM will have very similar properties to a weighted regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I check whether or not all coefficients for terms involving x1 are zero using a Wald test and find that I cannot reject the hypothesis that they are zero, but then looking at the interaction terms individually, I find the interaction term x1x2 has a p-value <0.05. How can this be possible?

You might think about this as similar to the problem with [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). The more comparisons you make, the more likely that a single comparison might appear to be "significant" by chance. Alternatively, if you do a lot of comparisons most of which aren't "significant" and account appropriately for the multiple comparisons, you can mask a truly "significant" result

A Wald test on multiple coefficients evaluates the quadratic form produced by the coefficient estimates and the inverse of their covariance matrix against a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the number of coefficients. Even if one of those coefficients is actually "significant," including multiple insignificant coefficients in the multiple-coefficient test can swamp out the "significance."

As a crude illustration, remember that the chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom used as the null distribution represents the sum of the squares of $k$ independent standard normal variables. The mean of that distribution is $k$. For a single coefficient you might have a "significant" chi-square statistic of 5:

```
1-pchisq(5,df=1)
# [1] 0.02534732
```

but if you add in 3 more standard normal variates contributing a total of 3 (mean under the null) to the combined chi-square statistic in a 4-coefficient Wald test the overall "significance" at p < 0.05 disappears.

```
1-pchisq(5+3,df=4)
# [1] 0.09157819
```

That's one reason why it's typically best to have some specific pre-specified hypotheses rather than throwing everything into the model and seeing what turns out to be "significant."